# How to install the "simple" package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to follow this tutorial on using R

http://wiener.math.csi.cuny.edu/Statistics/R/simpleR/stat019.html

One of its snippets references the `simple` package:

> simple.lm(cyl,mpg)

But *where* is that package??

```
> library(simple)
Error in library(simple) : there is no package called ‘simple’
> library(Simple)
Error in library(Simple) : there is no package called ‘Simple’
> library(simple)
Error in library(simple) : there is no package called ‘simple’
> install.packages(simple)
Error in install.packages(simple) : object 'simple' not found
> install.packages(Simple)
Error in install.packages(Simple) : object 'Simple' not found
```

Comment: You should also read the preface: http://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/Statistics/R/simpleR/. It is written: *The data sets are available in an R package, UsingR, which can be downloaded through the R command `install.packages("UsingR")`*

Comment: package `UsingR`. install.packages("UsingR")

Comment: @Pascal  That was *not* on the same page. Thanks for the info: but some others seem to be downvoting as if I were  completely lazy.

Comment: I just followed the advice: *This is version 0.4 of these notes and were last generated on August 22, 2002. Before printing these notes, you should check for the most recent version available from the CSI Math department*. It took less than 2 minutes to get information on how to find `simple.lm` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
install.packages("simple")
```

But [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/UsingR/docs/simple.lm) suggest that you need to do

```
install.packages("UsingR")
library(UsingR)
simple.lm(  )
```

Comment: I got downvoted for asking this question. How does one discover which package a function belongs to?

Comment: @javadba  It is written in the preface of the site: http://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/Statistics/R/simpleR/

Comment: I used Google "R simple.lm". The same function name may occur in multiple packages (often by design. e.g. "plot" is implemented in many packages). But in this case it seems there is no package called 'simple'

Comment: @Pascal  And once again stated:  that is not such an obvious link that you make it.

Comment: @javadba And once again, I just followed the advice given in the preface of the site you linked: *This is version 0.4 of these notes and were last generated on August 22, 2002. Before printing these notes, you should check for the most recent version available from the CSI Math department.*